# jquery.flipster not showing when hiding and showing 2 carousels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to incorporate 2 carousels into my web application using jquery.flipster: https://github.com/drien/jquery-flipster

However i am only every trying to show one carousel at a time. When i click on a tag to hide the first and show the second, the second is not appearing. Inspecting the element in Firefox, i can see the `<ul>` below the `class="flipster"` is not given a height or width on hide/show:

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-1">
    <h2>Carousel 1</h2>
    <div class="flipster">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <p class="show-carousel-2">Click Me to toggle both carousels</p>


  <div class="carousel-2">
    <h2>Carousel 2</h2>
    <div class="flipster">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $(".flipster").flipster({
        style: 'carousel',
        enableNav: false,
        enableNavButtons: true,
        start: 0
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".carousel-2").hide();

      $( ".show-carousel-2" ).click(function() {
        $( ".carousel-1" ).toggle( "slow" );
        $( ".carousel-2" ).toggle( "slow" );
      });

    });
  </script>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mqclzHJ1lLZCgr4j23AR?p=preview

I have even tried forcing a height and width via:

```
$( ".js-inject-carousel-css" ).css({"height": "176px !important", "width": "140px !important"});
```

When adding the `class js-inject-carousel-css` to the `<ul>`

Still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and resolved this issue.

Instead of:

```
$( ".js-inject-carousel-css" ).css({"height": "176px !important", "width": "140px !important"});
```

I used:

```
$( ".js-inject-carousel-css" ).css({"height": "176px", "width": "140px"});
```

Essentially i removed the `!important`. This was stopping jQuery insert the CSS values.